# Difference between Bubble sort and framework predefined sort C#

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a normal sort

What is the difference with normal sort and bubble sort?  there not are bubble method?

Comment: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/ take a look at this, see if this helps..~~

Comment: Thank You for your time!

Comment: `Array.Sort` is the sort method in the framework, which uses `QuickSort` or other type of sort depending on situation. Basically, there's no difference in 'output' but there are differences in the process. The differences between these different type of sorting are mainly time and space complexity.

Answer (score 2):

> what is the difference with this and bubble sort?

See the documentation for [Array.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc(v=vs.110).aspx).  Here's what it actually does:

> This method uses the introspective sort (introsort) algorithm as follows:
>
> - If the partition size is fewer than 16 elements, it uses an insertion
>     sort algorithm.
> - If the number of partitions exceeds 2 * LogN, where N
>     is the range of the input array, it uses a Heapsort algorithm.
> - Otherwise, it uses a Quicksort algorithm.